# Sending mail from local host to Gmail but mail is not sent

Tags: c#, asp.net

My Code on Button_Click is

```
Massage = "Name :" + txtname.Text + "\nEmail :" + txtemail.Text + "\nPhone :" + TextBox3.Text + "\nMassage :" + TextBox4.Text;
eMail.Mail(null, "contact us", "vermarajneesh344@gmail.com", null, null, "contact us", Massage, null, null);
```

and the code behind is

```
public class eMail
{
    public static bool Mail(string FromEmailAddress, string FromDisplayName, string ToAddress, string ToAddressCC, string ToAddressBCC, string Subject, string bodytxt, string HostName, string AttachFileName)
    {
    bool functionReturnValue = false;

    //*******example 

    //// System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.SmtpServer is obsolete in 2.0 
    //// System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient is the alternate class for this in 2.0 
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FromEmailAddress))
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromEmailAddress"].ToString()))
                FromEmailAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromEmailAddress"].ToString();


        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(FromEmailAddress, FromDisplayName);

        // // You can specify the host name or ipaddress of your server 
        //// Default in IIS will be localhost 


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HostName))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostName"].ToString()))
                HostName = "smtp.gmail.com"; //"mail.osmor.org";
            else
                HostName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostName"].ToString();
        }
        smtpClient.Host = HostName;

        ////Default port will be 25 
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpClientPort"].ToString()))
            smtpClient.Port = 465;
        else
            smtpClient.Port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpClientPort"].ToString());


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ESSL"].ToString()))
        {
            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ESSL"].ToString() == "true")
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            else
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
        }

        ////From address will be given as a MailAddress Object 
        message.From = fromAddress;

        //// To address collection of MailAddress 

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ToAddress))
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ToAddress"].ToString()))
                ToAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ToAddress"].ToString();

        string[] tmp = null;
        int i = 0;
        tmp = Mainclass.SplitByString(ToAddress, ",");
        for (i = 0; i <= tmp.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            message.To.Add(tmp[i].ToString());
            //"firsttime@sector-17.com") 
            message.Subject = Subject;
            //"Feedback" 
        }



        //// CC and BCC optional 
        //// MailAddressCollection class is used to send the email to various users 
        // // You can specify Address as new MailAddress("admin1@yoursite.com") 
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ToAddressCC))
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ToCC"].ToString()))
                ToAddressCC = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ToCC"].ToString();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ToAddressCC))
        {
            tmp = Mainclass.SplitByString(ToAddressCC, ",");

            for (i = 0; i <= tmp.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                message.CC.Add(tmp[i].ToString());
                // 
            }
        }
        //ToAddressBCC = "amangargptl@gmail.com";
        // // You can specify Address directly as string 
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ToAddressBCC))
        {
            tmp = Mainclass.SplitByString(ToAddressBCC, ",");
            for (i = 0; i <= tmp.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                message.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(tmp[i].ToString()));
            }
        }
        // //message.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("admin4@yoursite.com")); 

        ////Body can be Html or text format 
        // //Specify true if it is html message 
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

        String UserName, Password;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"].ToString()))
            UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"].ToString();
        else
            UserName = "UserName";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString()))
            Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString();
        else
            Password = "Password";

        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);

       //// Message body content 
        message.Body = bodytxt;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AttachFileName))
            message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + AttachFileName)));


        // // Send SMTP mail 
        smtpClient.Send(message);
                    // lblStatus.Text = "Email successfully sent."; 
        functionReturnValue = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        bodytxt = "Send Email Failed.<br>" + ex.Message;
        //; 
        //Mainclass.WriteErorrFile(ex.Message, "Macadamia", "Mail");  
        //c.msg(ex.Message, response) 
        functionReturnValue = false;
     //   throw;
    }
    return functionReturnValue;
}
```

and code on web.config is

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="bh" value="Travel  Holidays"/>
    <add key="FromEmailAddress" value="info@Travelholidays.com"/>
    <add key="ToAddress" value=""/>
    <add key="ToCC" value=""/>
    <add key="HostName" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
    <add key="UserName" value="info@Travelholidays.com"/>
    <add key="Password" value="password"/>
    <add key="smtpClientPort" value="587"/>
    <add key="ESSL" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Thanks..
help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: From my experience, you can only use smtp.gmail.com if you use gmail credentials.

Comment: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required

Comment: As expected. Try providing gmail credential to `smtpClient` and you should be okey.

Comment: this will not working

Comment: How do you know unless you try?

Answer (score 1):

Use these setting in your web.config

```
 <system.net>
  <mailSettings>
   <smtp from="sender@gmail.com ">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" defaultCredentials="false"
      port="587" enableSsl="true" userName="Sender@gmail.com"  password="*******" />
  </smtp>
 </mailSettings>
 </system.net>
```

In your .aspx.cs use

```
StringBuilder emailMessage = new StringBuilder();  
emailMessage.Append("Email body here");  

MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
 email.To.Add(new MailAddress("ReceiverEmailAddress"));  
 email.Subject = "Mail Subject";
        email.From = new MailAddress("sender@gmail.com");
        email.Body = emailMessage.ToString();
        email.IsBodyHtml = true;
        //Send Email;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Send(email);
```

That's it. Hope it works